# Что делает оператор "-->"?

Tags: c++, c

После прочтения [Hidden Features and Dark Corners of С++/STL](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/msg/33f173780d58dd20) на `comp.lang.c++.moderated`, я был удивлен  тому что следующий фрагмент, скомпилировался и работает в `Visual Studio 2008`, так и в `g++ 4.4`.

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    while (x --> 0) // x goes to 0
    {
        printf("%d ", x);
    }
}
```

Я предположил, что это `C`, так как он работает `Visual Studio 2008` и в `GCC`. Где это определено в стандарте и откуда взялся такое оператор?

<sub>свободный перевод вопроса [What is the "-->" operator in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c)</sub>

Comment: Зачем брать вопрос с qaru?

Comment: ассоциация: [What is the “-->” operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/4340086)

Comment: @PavelMayorov    я не нашёл ссылки на "официальный" вопрос ;_; по этому решил оставить ссылку.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-->` не является оператором. Это фактически два отдельных оператора, `--` и `>`

С начало происходит операция `--` (минус единица от `x`) после сравнивание `x` с `0`

**Чтобы лучше понять, выражение можно записать следующим образом:**

```
while( (x--) > 0 )
```

`x` может уменьшаться ещё быстрее:

```
int x = 10;

while( 0 <---- x )
{
   printf("%d ", x);
}
```

результат:

```
8 6 4 2
```

Вы можете контролировать скорость с помощью стрелок!

```
int x = 100;

while( 0 <-------------------- x )
{
   printf("%d ", x);
}
```

результат:

```
90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10
```

;)

Comment: Оригиналы: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1642035/4340086 и https://stackoverflow.com/a/27672749/4340086

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляйте ссылку на оригинал когда что-то переводите.

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо за ссылку, просто у меня была ссылка qaru а настоящую  я так и не нашёл

Comment: то есть вы просто стырили перевод с другого сайта? Не нужно так делать...

Comment: Угу, так и есть: *"Условный код уменьшается x, возвращая x исходное (не уменьшенное) значение"*. Фу!